# Mac Ethernet "Self-Assigned IP" when plugged into Switch

Tags: networking, mac, switch

I recently purchased a tp-link 16-Port Gigabit switch for my home and put all my network cables through it.

While my PC running Windows 10 works fine, my iMac (20-inch, Early 2008, Running Yosemite) isn't and flips to "Self-Assigned IP" after.

I tried switching the network cables between the PC and the Mac.  The PC accepts the new cable fine, the Mac tries and goes back to "Self-Assigned IP"

I tried switching that particular cable attached to the Mac from coming off the Switch to coming off my Belkin router and then it works fine.

Initially the Wifi didn't work either but I tried restarting the modem, router & switch and now I can get the wifi to connect but not the Ethernet.

I also tried all the tips I found online including disabling passive FTP and deleting com.apple.alf.plist and none of those seemed to work

As a temporary fix I have kept that particular cable plugged into the router but I'm curious if anyone has any ideas

Thanks!

Comment: All I can think of is a DHCP conflict. Assuming you added a switch because you have a large number of devices to plug in. Try this, unplug/shut down all devices from the switch and Belkin. Leave just the switch plugged in to the Belkin. Now, reboot the Belkin. Once it is online, plug in the Mac to the switch. See if you get a valid IP address. Now, one by one power on/re-connect other devices. If all these devices were 'ON' when you were adding this switch there could be a conflict of IP addresses.

Comment: @Appleoddity I figured it out.  I was going Modem > Switch > Router.  I changed this to Modem > Router > Switch and all is well.  I couldn't have done it without your advice so thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, I resolved this issue by changing the order of the devices.  The error was happening when I had it setup as Modem to Switch to Router.  By changing this to Modem to Router to Switch I immediately resolved the issue.  I hope this helps another networking newbie in the future.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, that will do it. The thought never crossed my mind maybe the basics weren't right. :)